# Command prompt makes all typed characters some weird symbol

Tags: windows, windows-10, console

All of my console windows somehow started misreading input. Numbers, letters, and other characters all showed up as a character P with a box around it. New console windows also had this problem.

It wasn't just a display issue: Python read `=` as a name, giving a name error instead of a syntax error.

(I'm making this post to document the problem and try to figure out what I did to make it stop happening. Please add more search terms as needed.)

Answer (score 1):

Locking the login (Windows + L) and logging back in fixed it. Switching accounts may have the same effect.

It happened again later.